# Sitecore.MobileSDK.SSC - How to count the item versions

Tags: mobile

Is there a way to get a count of item versions in `Sitecore.MobileSDK.SSC`?

I have the item instance and I need to know how many versions this item has.

On the Sitecore, I can see how many versions an item has. With this information, I can navigate through the Sitecore tree, access an item and get a specific version.

[image]

I will show to the user the content of an item, but first I need to know if this specific item has more than 1 version. With this information, I can show to the user a way to select which version he wants to see.

```
using (var credentials = new ScUnsecuredCredentialsProvider(UserName, Password, Domain))
    using (var session =
           SitecoreSSCSessionBuilder.AuthenticatedSessionWithHost(InstanceUrl)
           .Credentials(credentials)
           .BuildSession())
    {
        var request = ItemSSCRequestBuilder.ReadItemsRequestWithId(RequestID)
            .Database(Database)
            .Language(Language)
            .Build();

        ScItemsResponse items = await session.ReadItemAsync(request);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sitecoreItemList.Add(item);
            //here I need to count these item version.
        }

        return sitecoreItemList;
    }
```

Comment: Would be helpful in this case, if you shared with us the problem you are trying to solve rather than just _how_ you're trying to solve it. Your request is unusual for most use-cases.

Comment: I will show to the user the content of an item, but first I need to know if this specific item has more than 1 version. With this information, I can show to the user a way to select which version he wants to see.

Comment: On a published website?

Comment: No, my app will execute only on the Master Database.